# Serialize enum to integer values

Tags: kotlin, gson

I have the following enum:

```
enum class Scopes(val value: Int) {
    NODE(0),
    API(1),
    PROJECT(2),
    GLOBAL_TO_OWNER(3),
    PUBLIC_TO_ANYONE(4)
}
```

I would like to serialize this so that the enum value (its ordinal) is exported as an integer and not as a string. Example:

```
{"scope": 1}
```

What I don't want is:

```
{"scope": "1"}
```

If this can be done using Gson, that is preferred. If not, perhaps a native Kotlin approach might do.

Answer (score 1):

simple override of `serialize` should do it

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.google.gson.JsonElement
import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
import java.lang.reflect.Type

enum class Scopes(val value: Int) : JsonSerializer<Scopes> {
    NODE(0), API(1), PROJECT(2), GLOBAL_TO_OWNER(3), PUBLIC_TO_ANYONE(4);

    override fun serialize(p0: Scopes?, p1: Type?, p2: JsonSerializationContext?): JsonElement =
        JsonObject().apply { addProperty(p0?.name, p0?.value) }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val s = Scopes.NODE
    val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Scopes::class.java, Scopes.API).create()
    val jsonString = gson.toJson(s)
    println(jsonString)
}
```

Comment: The enum is used as part of a larger JSON object, so I'm not sure how this would work. val s = Scopes.NODE is just referring to a single enum member. I kept my code sample simple. A more realistic one would be {"id": "abc", scopeId: 2, "name": "Steve" }. This entire JSON object is created using toJson on some class instance and not just the enum I showed. I've seen registerTypeAdapter in other SO samples, but seems like a lot of code to just get an int.